# Kubernetes: Have stateful sets use the same external port

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, port

I have a Kafka stateful sets with 3 replicas: I am using the kafka helm chart available [here](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/incubator/kafka) and the confluentinc/Kafka 5.3.1 image. I am using annotation to make sure each run on a different node. I want to open the same external port on each pods. Currently the helm charts open ports 9092 internal and (31090 + the replica number) as external. I am using affinity to make sure that the pods are deployed on different hosts. I am also using an ingress to connect to a load balancer on AWS. 
How can I have the same external port number on each Kafka pods that are running on the different nodes?

Thank you

Comment: you edit the nodeport and set the target port also in helm chart simply edit the chart.

Comment: I am getting an error saying 'port already in use'

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need affinity rules?

Comment: i am trying to connect to an AWS loadbalancer and it needs to connect to the same port

Answer (score 0):

The increasing NodePort number is by design according to the Helm chart. You can see the definition for incrementing the port number starting from the `firstListenerPort` defined in your Helm chart (default 31090) in [this file](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/incubator/kafka/templates/service-brokers-external.yaml) line 9:

```
{{- $externalListenerPort := add $root.Values.external.firstListenerPort $i }}
```

You can fork the Helm chart, and then modify `templates/service-brokers-external.yaml` to replace references of `$externalListenerPort` with `$firstListenerPort`. In your Helm chart values definition, you can change the common NodePort number by modifying the `external.firstListenerPort`.